# NSDate different in simulator and device(ipad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi I am converting a GMT time to local time in my project - I getting the correct value in all simulator and in iPhone/iPod - but when I run this in iPad I am getting null,
Here is my code -

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"14:37:00"];  


NSLog(@"startDate---%@",startDate);

//This is startDate---2000-01-01 14:37:00 +0000 (in simulator/iPod/iphone)
 //  startDate---(null)  (in ipad)
```

**Issue is with user's ipad's time format - if it is in 12 hour format - then the above code results null
What do I do for this issue ??**

Comment: bacause you time format is set to 12 hours on ipad device, the date string is in 24 hours format look at string @"14:37:00" check it.

Comment: @pawan - that is right - it is working if I changed time format to 24 hours. So what do I do for if users device is in 12 hour format ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bacause you time format is set to 12 hours on ipad device, the date string is in 24 hours format look at string @"14:37:00".

use

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

if you want to force it to 12-hour mode, regardless of the user's 24/12 hour mode setting, you should set the locale to en_US_POSIX.

Use hh instead of HH.

hh usually is 12 hour time while HH is usually 24 hour time.

A good official reference for this, [as linked by Apple themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13), is [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Another good table is [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), as mentioned by Zaph.

Comment: Yes this is right - but I am getting this time "14:37:00" from server - and it is in 24 hours format all the time, So what do i do for this,

Comment: [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]; will force the 24 hour date to 12 hours , try this.